# laravel eloquent using a scope to compare 2 columns

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 date columns in the users table of laravel 5.0. The schema is:

users
  * id
  * email
  * activated_on
  * deactivated_on

I want to query if the user is activated so I have the following scope function:

```
public function scopeActivated($query){
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    return $query->whereBetween('activated_on', ['deactivated_on', $now]);
}
```

The query that this generates is that it compares the column `activated_on` to the string `deactivated_on`.

Is there a way to tell eloquent to compare the 2 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try whereRaw function

```
$query->whereRaw('activated_on < deactivated_on AND activated_on > ?', array($now));
```

Comment: Do you know how well this works across the other database types?  I know it works in sqlite, but what about postgres and sql server?

Comment: Actually, i didnt try it on postgres or sql server. A few years ago i need it on  mysql , i think it works on mysql but i'm not totally sure.